# Cancelling Web workers

Tags: javascript

I have a web worker but I'd like it to terminate early and be replaced if a new request comes in, calling .terminate() seems to kill it completely, I just want it to stop any processing on a previous request.

Here's some example code, I only want the most recent slider value any uncompleted ones should be cancelled for better performance -

**index.html**

```
<input type="range" id="inputRange"/>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
var worker = new Worker("worker.js")
document.getElementById("inputRange").oninput = function(e) {
  worker.postMessage(e.target.value);
}
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  document.getElementById("result").textContent=e.data;
}
</script>
```

**worker.js**

```
onmessage = function (args) {
  var total=0;
    for (var i=0;i<1000000;i++)
      total+=args.data*Math.random()
  postMessage(args.data+"="+Math.floor(total));
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Glam0SsPonmngep8YWPq?p=preview

Comment: what do you mean with *the most recent slider value*?

Comment: if you drag the slider lots of values are fired, I'm only interested in the final one (I realize I could change the slider event but this is an arbitrary example to understand web workers.)

Comment: and why haven't you set params for your `range` like `min="0" max="180" step="20"` ?

Comment: this is an arbitrary example to understand web workers not input ranges

Answer (score 0):

In your web worker, you can in include the callback race condition whth the help of the [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) method.

- The 1st Promise realise the normal behaviour, and will be resolved when the process is terminated.
- The 2nd Promise is fulfilled when the Web Worker will get a new message.

As soon as the one the promises resolves, the `Promise.race()` will resolve itself.